# WSO2 CEP IBM MQ and transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers

Tags: performance, jms, wso2, ibm-mq, wso2-cep

I have a WSO2 CEP configured with Input Event Adaptor set to listen on a IBM WebSphere MQ queue. Below there is a conf in xml:

```
<inputEventAdaptor name="WEBSPHEREMQ" statistics="disable" trace="disable" type="jms" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventadaptormanager">
  <property name="java.naming.provider.url">file:/opt/bindings</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">false</property>
  <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">MQ_JMS_MANAGER</property>
  <property name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</property>
</inputEventAdaptor>
```

and an event builder with queue set:

```
<from eventAdaptorName="WEBSPHEREMQ" eventAdaptorType="jms">
  <property name="transport.jms.Destination">MSCRM_IN_JMS_QUEUE</property>
</from>
```

I want to increase transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers to speed up CEP performance results. Where do I need to put this parameter? I have tried in event adaptor and in event builder but it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for any help!:)

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Sorry at the moment, there is no any way to pass this property out of the box to jms adaptor. But I strongly believe this is a good addition for jms adaptor. We are doing some improvements related to this by aiming next release.. I have created a jira [1] to track this..

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-884

you have two option at the moment, improve the current input jms adaptor by fixing in the source or write a custom jms adaptor for you need..

Thanks,Mohan